# Error: Could not find the sentinel when trying to build node executable

Tags: node.js, executable

I am trying to create an executable using node using the instructions at https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v19.x/api/single-executable-applications.html. More specifically, I have tried the following commands in my macOS terminal:

```
echo 'console.log(`Hello, ${process.argv[2]}!`);' > hello.js
cp /Users/sabo/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/node hello
codesign --remove-signature hello
npx postject hello NODE_JS_CODE hello.js --sentinel-fuse NODE_JS_FUSE_fce680ab2cc467b6e072b8b5df1996b2 --macho-segment-name NODE_JS
```

However, the last command gives an error `Error: Could not find the sentinel NODE_JS_FUSE_fce680ab2cc467b6e072b8b5df1996b2 in the binary`. I have installed the sentinel binary on my machine - does anyone know what might be wrong/how I can troubleshoot?

Alternatively, my main goal is simply to build an executable based on node.js code that can run on a machine that doesn't necessarily have node.js installed. If the above instructions aren't ideal for doing so, does anyone know how I could possibly use only node18 tooling (and not another package like pkg) to build static binaries?

Comment: Have you found the solution?